# R download.file download raw html without images

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am downloading raw html websites with R's download.file function. 
For storage efficiency, I would like to know if it is possible to download the html-files without contained images. 
Something rings that I have heard about something like that before, but I can simply neither remember nor find any evidence/instructions.

I would be very grateful for some help.
Greetings,
Marcel

```
url_list <- c("http://www.spiegel.de/",
              "http://www.faz.net/")
dest_list <- c("test1.html",
               "test2.html")

download.file(url_list,
              dest_list,
              method="libcurl",
              quiet=F)
```

Comment: I would suggest using `rvest::read_html`, that way you're just getting the raw HTML data, rather than saving complete copies of each web page. Not sure what the default of `download.file(url)` is in regards to images though.

Comment: Another option is using the readLines function in base R.

Comment: Thank you. I think I would want the raw HTML data for reproducibility reasons though.

Comment: Unless the site has base64-encoded image content in it, you're just getting HTML with `download.file()` or `rvest::read_html()`. I don't know where anyone got the idea `download.file()` does a crawl of links on a page. It doesn't.